# Assigning the hat / caret / circumflex (above the tab) key as keybinding using dconf

Tags: bash, shell, key-bindings, linux-mint

I am trying to add a custom keybinding via the command line using `dconf` (on Mint 21.1 Cinnamon). I successfully managed to do that, e.g. for the keys <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>s</kbd>, with the following lines:

```
dconf write /org/cinnamon/desktop/keybindings/custom-list "['custom0']"     
dconf write /org/cinnamon/desktop/keybindings/custom-keybindings/custom0/command "'tilix --quake'"
dconf write /org/cinnamon/desktop/keybindings/custom-keybindings/custom0/name "'tilixquake'"
dconf write /org/cinnamon/desktop/keybindings/custom-keybindings/custom0/binding "['<Control>s']"
```

However, I would like to assign the "hat" / "caret" / "circumflex" key <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>^</kbd> as shortcut, but cannot get it to work.

[image]

I have tried different strings for the binding in the last line, but none of them worked:

```
"['<Control>^']"

"['<Control>Hat']"

"['<Control><Hat>']"

"['<Control>Caret']"

"['<Control><Caret>']"

"['<Control>Circumflex']"

"['<Control><Circumflex>']"
```

How do I correctly address the <kbd>^</kbd> key so it works with `dconf`? Is there a list of possible key identifiers somewhere? I could not find one...

Comment: Ok, I just realized that the caret key is not always in the same place. See my [answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75483330/14015737).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after looking some more into it, I found the answer.

I was wondering whether maybe some pre-existing keybinding already used the <kbd>^</kbd> key and printed a list of all bindings using

```
gsettings list-recursively | fgrep org.cinnamon.desktop.keybindings
```

and in the output, I spotted a line

> org.cinnamon.desktop.keybindings.wm switch-group ['<Alt>Above_Tab']

It was not until I found this, that I realized that the <kbd>^</kbd> key is in different places in different keyboard layouts. In my German QWERTZ layout, it is the one above the <kbd>Tab</kbd>. In a QWERTY layout, the same key would be a backtick.

Either way, using `Above_Tab` as identifier for <kbd>^</kbd>, I could successfully set the keybinding:

```
dconf write /org/cinnamon/desktop/keybindings/custom-list "['custom0']"     
dconf write /org/cinnamon/desktop/keybindings/custom-keybindings/custom0/command "'tilix --quake'"
dconf write /org/cinnamon/desktop/keybindings/custom-keybindings/custom0/name "'tilixquake'"
dconf write /org/cinnamon/desktop/keybindings/custom-keybindings/custom0/binding "['<Control>Above_Tab'
```